# Is there a way to render the document attributes of an asciidoc file and output to an adoc file?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Consider the following example

```
:title: An AsciiDoc file
:CustomAttribute: XYZ

= {title}

Some paragraphs.

[comment]
--
Some comments including that {CustomAttribute} variable.
--

// EOF
```

Is there anyway I could render the above file with AsciiDoc/AsciiDoctor into

```
:title: An AsciiDoc file
:CustomAttribute: XYZ

= An AsciiDoc file

Some paragraphs.

[comment]
--
Some comments including that XYZ variable.
--

// EOF
```

... so that I could extract/work with the latest attributes?
I've found nothing in the documentation, but I might have overlooked it.

The alternatives I see at the moment would require writing a script to make those substitutions and extract the information I need before converting the AsciiDoc file.

Perhaps there is a much simpler approach; any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, Asciidoctor does not generate AsciiDoc. Once the [AsciiDoc Language Specification](https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse/asciidoc-lang/asciidoc-lang) is complete, generating AsciiDoc will be possible.

You could use a script, as you suggested, to cement the attribute values. Another alternative might be:

1. Generate DocBook XML using Asciidoctor:

   ```
   asciidoctor -b file.adoc
   ```
2. Use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert the DocBook XML to AsciiDoc:

   ```
   pandoc -f docbook -t asciidoc -o file-no_attributes.adoc file.xml
   ```

Note: if you replace `file.adoc` with `file-no_attributes.adoc`, you won't see future attribute updates because they have been replaced with plain text.

Comment: Thank you @eskwayrd.
I'm pretty sure that such a step it's already available during the pre-processing of the document by AsciiDoctor, but not exposed to the user.
Anyway, I decided to add another script step to my tooling making a copy of the latest adoc, and replacing all the document attributes in order to extract the information I needed.